EF Core 6 : can I set an entity value from a different table?
I am looking for a way to set up my context so that when it populates a particular property of a particular entity, it pulls the data from a different table. Something similar to this fake syntax (assuming navigation properties are already in place) and made-up schema:
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity => {
  entity.Property(e => e.PropFromOtherTable)
    // the magic I'm looking for
    .PopulateFrom(e => e.Destination?.Hotel.Contact.Id ?? 0);
}

Ideally I'd like to do this in the model builder so the property will be populated in all the places this entity is being used, without having to explicitly ask for the property in any given query.
I realize I can use Select to get any shape I want, but my primary motivator here is avoiding having to change the signatures of 40+ methods and 150+ unit tests, and without having to pull in a ton of extra data (ultimately, I just need the contact id, I don't need hotels or contacts).

Short answer: no, EF doesn't have formula properties as NHibernate has.

Maybe create view and map to this view? Also see Table-valued function mapping

Yeah I considered a view but this is a widely used class that other places will have to update. Changing everything over to use a view for this 1 use case (and to avoid extra work) seems like a bad idea :), and creating a new view/object introduces the same "change the signature" problem I want to avoid. But thanks, It's a good idea!

Short answer: No, with exceptions using table splitting relationships you can pull entity values from related tables. Using view models and projections such as Automapper or Mapperly it would be trivial as these wrap the "work" of building a Select query expression on reads to have EF dive through the domain model and pull just the fields you want to consume.
You could consider updating your schema to include a computed column on the table(s) to fetch the related ContactId then you can map that in the entity to be treated as a computed value. (Read-only) This would probably be the cleanest option to get that property into your entity. This works similarly to an Identity column, just configure it as [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]. If you are using Code-First to manage your schema you would need to set up how to select the Client ID.
Another option is an unmapped, client-side computed column such as:
public class MyEntity
{
    // ...

    [NotMapped]
    public int ContactId => Destination?.Hotel.Contact.Id ?? 0;
}

However this would only be reliable when any applicable Destination + Hotel + Contact was eager loaded or pre-populated by the DbContext, or you have lazy loading enabled. (which would be a rather expensive property to read since it would load the entire destination, hotel, and contact to get this property) If the property is only accessed infrequently and not going to be "touched" on things like list iterations that's not a completely terrible situation for lazy loading, but does pose a land mine situation where it could cause performance issues.
A "hacky" approach using Automapper (Or other IQueryable supported mappers like Mapperly) is projecting to detached entities where you don't work with view models. Similar to the unmapped client-side computed value above we use an unmapped property:
public class MyEntity
{
    // ...

    [NotMapped]
    public int ContactId { get; protected set; }
}

We then have an Automapper configuration. I typically put these as static methods on my view models, but we can add to the entity as an example:
    public static MapperConfiguration BuildConfig()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(config => 
            config.CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntity>()
                .ForMember(x => x.ContactId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Destination.Hotel.Contact.Id ?? 0));

);
return config;
}
Then when reading our entities, inject the ProjectTo<MyEntity> before ToList() or FirstOrDefault() etc where this entity is read:
I.e.
 var myEntity = context.MyEntities
     .Where(x => ...)
     .ProjectTo<MyEntity>(MyEntity.BuildConfig())
     .ToList();

The caveat of this approach is that the resulting entities will be Detached, so if you want to perform updates you will need to attach them. This means checking for existing tracked entities in the DbContext first. Entities read without the projection will not have the ContactId available. You cannot use the ContactId property to change the contact, that has to be done through Destination.Hotel.Contact and note that changing that association will not automatically refresh the ContactId on the MyEntity. You would want to have a more DDD approach on the entity such as "MyEntity.ChangeDestination(Destination)" which would update the destination and re-compute the ContactId.  Honestly it would be better to use ViewModels to avoid the confusion and hassle that can be caused with detached entities and unmapped properties. Though it is an option you can explore.

These are some good ideas. I didn't mention this was MS SQL server, but it is and I don't think its computed columns can read from any other table (or even any other row), at least not nicely. I definitely wanted to avoid the situation where each individual query has to take an explicit extra step to populate the field, because I don't want anyone to see the field is available but wonder why its not populating.
These are very interesting ideas, but I don't think they'll fit with this codebase or team. Ah well, I will bite the bullet and do the right thing and get the code cleaned up. Thanks!

There's no real magic in EF to do this. If you must have magic, you can perhaps rely on a database trigger to populate the field on insert, but be aware that you'll need to refresh the object from the database in EF to see that value. I would recommend against this, however.
I would set up a service that does this for you. This way you can write a test easier. I know you mention you don't want to update all of the existing code, but this is an opportunity to clean that up. Don't make a mess messier.

Hahaha yep this is some pretty messy and janky code. I'm probably going to end up doing some cleanup, the question is just where to stop :)
